# Inequalities involving definite integrals in $\mathcal{C}[a,b]$

Tags: real-analysis, real-numbers

> Let $f \in \mathcal{C}[a,b]$. Assume that $\min_{x \in [a,b]} f(x)=m>0$ and let $M=\max_{ x \in [a,b]}f(x)$. Which of the following inequalities are true?
>
> $(A)$ $\frac{1}{M} \int\limits_a^b f(x) \ dx + m \int\limits_a^b \frac{1}{f(x)} \ dx \geq 2 \sqrt{\frac{m}{M}}(b-a)$
>
> $(B)$ $\int\limits_a^b f(x) \ dx \int\limits_a^b \frac{1}{f(x)} \ dx \geq (b-a)^2$
>
> $(C)$ $ \int\limits_a^b f(x) \ dx \int\limits_a^b \frac{1}{f(x)} \ dx \leq (b-a)^2$

So according to answer at the back **$A \& B$** are the correct options. $B$ is clear to me you replace $f$ and $1/f$ on the $LHS$ by its appropriate bounds to attain the inequality. I am not sure how to attack $A$. Any help?

Comment: Is it a homework? This same question has already appeared here at least two more time within the last hour.

Comment: You only have to use $f(x) \leq M, f(x) \geq m, 1/f(x) \leq 1/m, 1/f(x) \geq 1/M$.

Comment: @zipirovich No. I am working through previous years question papers from the Notional Board of Mathematics (India).

Comment: Apparently, tonight's the night for working thru last year's NBMI. See http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2104065/nbhm-question-2013-riemann-integration-related-question